# What does XIRR show?

Tags: finance

I've put aside 1000 EUR for trading strategy test. Made number of trades where each position was worth 5 EUR. At any moment there was invested from 0 to 80 EUR. Entered all cashflows to XIRR function and it shows 0,14. What does it mean? I suppose it means 14% return from some sum over some period. I assume the period is 1 year, but what is the sum that gives 14%? Should I somehow add funds that sit idle?

For example I bought an asset on 1st of Jan for 5 EUR and in 3 days sold it with 0,2 EUR profit. Cashflows for this trade are:

2021-01-01; -5

2021-01-04; +5

2021-01-04; +0,2

Comment: Welcome! Your question is not completely clear to me. You might want to provide a description (perhaps a simplified example ) of the cash flow data you entered into XIRR. What counts as a Cash Flow?

Comment: Added an example of cash flow data entered into XIRR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its simplest form, for a series of irregular and/or intermittent cashflows that defy description in traditional terms (like bond coupons, dividends, etc.)...

XIRR tells you "what interest rate would a bank have to offer to give me the same end result, given all the same cashflows at the same times?".

The implicit and necessary assumption being a constant equivalent interest rate over the whole period.

Comment: I still don't understand on what amount does that constant interest is based on. 14% from 100 EUR and 14% from 1000 EUR  is not the same.

Comment: Or do I understand correctly, that each time I invested 5 EUR for 3 days, equivalent interest rate for same duration same size deposit should be 14% or the XIRR value?

Comment: OK, so imagine you invested 100 on 31/12 and it doubled in January. So you take out half, ie 100 (leaving you with 100). The market falls 10% in Feb, (90) so you put 200 in (290). The market is flat in Feb, but you get a bonus so you put in 1,000 (1290). The market then rises 10% (1419); but you need 500 to help out a friend (919). How much have you had invested, the "correct amount"? The whole point of XIRR is to create a consistent and intuitive measure of returns, when there is no such capital figure because it itself changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

OP, I assume you have done a modicum of research on the concept of "internal rate of return"? If so, what, exactly, is not clear? Explaining what is not clear would be more helpful than asking for an explanation of a concept.

### Some examples

XIRR calculates the internal rate of return for a set of irregular cashflows. There are plenty of resources on what this means, so I am not going to repeat the definition here.

Say you invest 100 now, then you get 10 of interest after 1 year and 110 (principal + interest) after 2 years. Your IRR is 10%, and you can calculate it with Excel's IRR function. The easiest, non-mathematically rigorous interpretation is that this is the return you make if you lend 100 now, get 10 of interest after 1 year, then at Y2 you get 10 of interest and your principal back.

Now imagine the same cashflows happen on: 1-May-2021, 1-Feb-2022, and 1-Dec-2022. The IRR will be 12.80% and you can calculate this with Excel's XIRR function. The interpretation is the same as above.

### A practice question for you

Let's say I lend €1000 to you and €1000 to your brother. In both cases, principal to be repaid after 1 year, and 5% interest. However, you pay me interest every month, your brother only after a year. Do you think the IRRs will be the same? Yes / no / why?

### A clarification

The IRR becomes a rather irrelevant metric when the time interval is small.
Let's say you buy something for 100 on 1-Jan and sell it for 110 on 1-Apr. Your IRR is 47.19%. If instead you sell it one week later, the IRR drops to 43.14%. In many cases (think of a manufacturer or retailer selling its inventory) selling a week later is not the end of the world - what does such a drop in IRR mean? Well, practically not much! In these cases, looking at the money multiple may be more relevant.

In fact, many real estate transactions are based on a combination of these two metrics. A counterparty gets paid more upon reaching certain targets of IRR and of money multiple. An example could be a real estate deal where your partner is tasked with selling the apartments you are building in a condo. A minimum money multiple ensures that a short timeframe doesn't distort the results, and a minimum high IRR ensures the opposite, ie that you don't pay too much for a high multiple obtained over too long a period.

Answer (score -1):

The XIRR is simply returning an effective annual rate. So, in order to achieve the XIRR you have to assume that the money stays fully invested for the entire year.

Comment: Effective rate for what amount of money? Cashflows does not show how much money I have aside for investing. Also cashflows might cover the same sum over different periods.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - the money does NOT need to remain invested for the whole year to achieve that return.

Comment: Take a simple example. Assume on 12/31/2020 you invest $100,000 and the next day on 1/1/2022 you get back 101,000. The XIRR function in Excel returns 5,542%. This is the effective annual rate. If you want your $100,000 initial investment to turn into 5,641,804 by the end of the year, then you have to assume it remains fully invested and continues earning the XIRR for the remainder of the year.

Comment: @LukeKrause No, not true. The IRR is simply the return obtained in a period of time. This period could be any length, one day (in which case the calculation would make little practical sense) or decades. There is no requirement whatsoever to 'remain invested for the whole year'.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous I agree with you for the IRR, but not for the XIRR. The XIRR is calculating an effective annual rate, so in order for your money to grow at the XIRR you need to keep it fully invested for the entire year. If you disagree, can you provide an example?

Comment: XIRR is not a concept, it is the name Microsoft gave to an Excel function which calculates the IRR. The concept of IRR is the very same whether you have regular or irregular cashflows, whether you calculate it with pen and paper, with Excel's IRR, Excel's XIRR, whether you code your own numerical function to find a solution, or whatever. If you invest 100 now and get 110 after half a year, your IRR is 21%. Period. I fail to see where remaining invested for the full year comes from.